# How to Read this JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a simple JSON and want to read in PHP. I am certainly missing something in array, can anybody point out my mistake. Its been considerable time I am playing with this simple thing.
Here is the JSON & php :

```
$string='[
    {
        "phone":"+91009999000",
        "name":"abcd",
        "typeid":1
    }
    {
        "phone":"+91009999222",
        "name":"efg",
        "typeid":2
    }
    {
        "phone":"+91009999444",
        "name":"hijhl",
        "typeid":1
    }
]';


$json_a = json_decode($string,true);            
$phone = $json_a[0]['phone'];
$full_name=$json_a[0]['courseid'];

echo "phone = " . $phone;
echo "<br>fullname = " . $full_name;
```

Comment: use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: you are missing commas in JSON string after each element (after closing curly brace)

Comment: This is not a valid json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing commas near curly braces.

It should be like this:

```
$string='[
            {
                "phone":"+91009999000",
                "name":"abcd",
                "typeid":1
            },
            {
                "phone":"+91009999222",
                "name":"efg",
                "typeid":2
            },
            {
                "phone":"+91009999444",
                "name":"hijhl",
                "typeid":1
            }
        ]';
```

Comment: It is, because when you do `json_decode($string)` it will give output like `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [phone] => +91009999000
            [name] => abcd
            [typeid] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [phone] => +91009999222
            [name] => efg
            [typeid] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [phone] => +91009999444
            [name] => hijhl
            [typeid] => 1
        )

)`

Comment: @Gulshan this is valid JSON. What make you think this isn't valid?